# change the EntireRow to only copy selected Column

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have this code

```
Sub TFS_Data_TC_Custody_Failed()
Dim bottomL As Integer
Dim x As Integer
bottomL = Sheets("TFS_Data_TC_Custody").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 3
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("TFS_Data_TC_Custody").Range("E2:E" & bottomL)
    If c.Value = "Failed" Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("TC_Custody_Failed").Range("A" & x)
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next c End Sub
```

I want to change the EntireRow to only copy selected Columns e.g. A,C,D of the rows that it has identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to create another `Range` object and use the `Intersect` method to keep only columns A,C, and D of the `EntireRow`

```
Sub TFS_Data_TC_Custody_Failed()
Dim bottomL As Integer
Dim x As Integer
bottomL = Sheets("TFS_Data_TC_Custody").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 3
Dim c As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
For Each c In Sheets("TFS_Data_TC_Custody").Range("E2:E" & bottomL)
    If c.Value = "Failed" Then
        Set copyRange = Application.Intersect(c.EntireRow, _
                        Sheets("TFS_Data_TC_Custody").Range("A:A,C:D"))
        copyRange.Copy Worksheets("TC_Custody_Failed").Range("A" & x)
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: When I attempt to do this i get an error:
Run-Time error '1004':
Method 'Intersect' of object'_Application' failed

Any ideas?

Comment: You may need to fully qualify the `Range("A:A,C:D")` object if "TFS_Data_TC_Custody" is not the `ActiveSheet` when running the sub. Code has been updated above

Comment: Thanks for this, this has fixed, I was wondering if you could help with am improvement. I am going to be putting comments next to the each items that is found to have Failed, the issue is when I run this code if one item has changed the order changes so the comments don't match with the specific item. Any ideas?

Comment: No probs Scott. I can't really help with the comments part without seeing the code you have. It's probably best to start up a new topic to get help with this. Also, if the original question is answered could you please accept? [Answered Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have posted the question now [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524438/entirerow-to-only-copy-selected-column-but-match-static-data-already-on-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would construct my code entirely differently but here is one way of doing it based on what you have. I didn't fully understand where you are placing the copied data so you may need to amend that part.

```
Dim bottomL As Integer
Dim x As Integer
bottomL = Sheets("TFS_Data_TC_Custody").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
x = 3
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("TFS_Data_TC_Custody").Range("E2:E" & bottomL)
    If c.Value = "Failed" Then
        c.Cells(1, 1).Copy Worksheets("TC_Custody_Failed").Range("A" & x) 
        c.Cells(1, 3).Copy Worksheets("TC_Custody_Failed").Range("A" & x + 1)
        c.Cells(1, 4).Copy Worksheets("TC_Custody_Failed").Range("A" & x + 2)
        x = x + 3
    End If
Next c
```